# Error fatal al introducir un insert, error del objeto

Tags: php, html

tengo un html donde quiero introducir un nuevo empleado. Resulta, que si previamente no creo un código de referencia no se puede introducir un empleado, hasta ahí todo correcto.

Cuando relleno los datos donde se encuentra el código de referencia, una descripción y el nombre del empleado y le doy a crear en este momento llama a un archivo php que os voy a dejar a continuación donde primero ejecuta un insert recogiendo el valor del input del código de referencia y lo crea. Esto lo hace bien, me lo crea.

A continuación hago un select donde guardo el id y luego una insert donde se lo paso pero me da este error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\beep\nuevo_empleado.php on line 33

Código:

```
<?php
      include 'cn.php';

    $codigo_empleado = $_POST["codigo_empleado"];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion_codigo'];
    $nombre_completo = $_POST['nombre_empleado'];

    /* CREAR CODIGO QUE NECESITAMOS PARA CREAR UN EMPLEADO*/
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO codigos(codigo,descripcion) VALUES ('$codigo_empleado','$descripcion');";
    $sql1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

    /* GUARDAR EL ID DE CODIGO INTRODUCIDO EN UNA VARIABLE PARA USARLO EN EL INSERT DEL NUEVO EMPLEADO*/
    $codigo_id = "SELECT codigos.id from codigos where codigos.codigo = ".$_POST["codigo_empleado"].";";
    $codigo_id = mysqli_query($conn,$codigo_id);

    /* INSERT PARA EL NUEVO EMPLEADO PASANDOLE EL CODIGO INTRODUCIDO*/
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO empleados(nombre_completo,codigo) values ('$nombre_completo', '$codigo_id');";
    $sql2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);



?>
```

Comment: Hola, muestranos var_dump() de: $sql1, $codigo_id y $sql2 antes de ejecutar la query porfavor.

Comment: Hola $codigo_id = mysqli_query($conn,$codigo_id); es una consulta que devuelve un objeto, del que no extraes el id, y luego tratas de usarlo como una cadena en el query siguiente $sql2 = "INSERT INTO empleados(nombre_completo,codigo) values ('$nombre_completo', '$codigo_id');"; ahí está el error

Comment: @quevedo como quedaría entonces el código?

Comment: Ya te respondí. Ten cuidado con el código porque es muy inseguro, Debes usar sentencias preparadas. Consulta [the only PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

Comment: Lo que me pregunto, aparte de que no funcione, es por qué tienes que hacer: a. Un `INSERT`; b. Un `SELECT` y c. Otro `INSERT`. ¿Por qué no creas relaciones entre las tablas?

Comment: @A.Cedano si no creo antes un código, no puedo crear un empleado por las fk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola voy a hacer unos pequeños ajustes a tu código. Aunque no estoy de acuerdo con el modo como pasas los parámetros. Debieras usar sentencias preparadas. Y, adicionalmente, en lo personal, recomiendo usar PDO para la conexión y las consultas.

```
<?php
// ajusto tu consulta:
 /* GUARDAR EL ID DE CODIGO INTRODUCIDO EN UNA VARIABLE PARA USARLO EN EL INSERT DEL NUEVO EMPLEADO*/
//Este query es inseguro admite inyección SQL ¡Consulta el tema!
$query_codigo = "SELECT codigos.id from codigos where codigos.codigo = ".$_POST["codigo_empleado"].";";
$result_codigo_id = mysqli_query($conn,$query_codigo);
// $result_codigo_id es un objeto de tipo mysqli_result
$linea = mysqli_fetch_row($result_codigo_id);
// Ahora si obtienes el código
$codigo_id = isset($linea['id']) ? $linea['id'] : '';
// Ahora si puedes usarlo.
```

Hago edición completa de la respuesta para ofrecer una variante usando PDO que protege de ataques de **inyección Sql** empleando sentencias preparadas.

En la primera parte ilustro como crear la conexión usando PDO, y debo anotar que se debe tener cuidado de no crear múltiples conexiones, de ser posible usar sólo una, para no agotar recursos del lado del servidor.

Creación de la conexión

```
<?php
// Archivo cn.php
// Ilustración del uso de una conexión PDO
use PDO; //Necesario aunque viene por defecto no está disponible sin referencia explícita
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=su_base_de_datos;host=localhost';
$username = 'root'; //puede ser otro con privilegios suficientes
$password = '******'; // el password de root o del usuario con privilegios suficientes
$options = [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8', ]; //Un array de opciones válidas consultar manual
$haycon = 0;
try{
  // Ojo en lo posible sólo se debe usar una conexión en todo el proceso para servir la página
  $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
  $haycon = 1;
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    // Hacer algo para notificar el error de conexión
    $haycon = 0;
}
?>
```

Ahora el código que hace uso de la conexión creada desde otro archivo

```
<?php
// Ahora un equivalente de tu código usando PDO
include 'cn.php';

if ($haycon){
    $codigo_empleado = isset($_POST["codigo_empleado"]) ? $_POST["codigo_empleado"] : '';
    $descripcion =  isset($_POST['descripcion_codigo']) ? : $_POST['descripcion_codigo'];
    $nombre_completo = isset($_POST['nombre_empleado']) ? $_POST['nombre_empleado'] : '';

    /* CREAR CODIGO QUE NECESITAMOS PARA CREAR UN EMPLEADO*/
    // preparo el query, observa que al usar hallders no necesito usar las comillas simples para las cadenas
    $query1 = "INSERT INTO codigos(codigo,descripcion) VALUES (:codigo, :descripcion);";
    $valores1 = [':codigo' => $codigo_empleado, ':descripcion'=>$descripcion];
    // y al pasar los valores en un array tampoco voy a necesitar hacer bind explicito
    $prepared = $connection->prepare($query1);
    $done = $prepared->execute($valores1);

    // si devuelve FALSE puedes usar algunos métodos del objeto para revisar y depurar
    // supongo que devolvión TRUE
    // cierro la sentencia, no se va a usar más
    $prepared->closeCursor();
    unset($prepared);

    /* GUARDAR EL ID DE CODIGO INTRODUCIDO EN UNA VARIABLE PARA USARLO EN EL INSERT DEL NUEVO EMPLEADO*/
    $query_codigo = "SELECT codigos.id from codigos where codigos.codigo = :codigo;";
    $valores=[':codigo' => $codigo_empleado];
    $prepared_consulta = $connection->prepare($query_codigo);
    $done = $prepared_consulta->execute($valores);
    if($done){
        $lectura = $prepared_consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $codigoid = (isset($lectura[0]['id'])) ? $lectura[0]['id'] : 0;
    }else{
        $codigoid = 0;
    }
    //Cierro el cursor abierto y libero recursos
    $prepared_consulta->closeCursor();
    unset($prepared_consulta);

    if($codigoid){
        /* INSERT PARA EL NUEVO EMPLEADO PASANDOLE EL CODIGO INTRODUCIDO*/
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO empleados(nombre_completo,codigo) values (:nombre, :codigoid);";
        $valores2 = [':nombre'=>$nombre_completo, ':codigoid'=>$codigoid];
        $prepared = $connection->prepare($sql2);
        $prepared->execute($valores2);
    }else{
        // reportar error
    }
}else{
    // Reportar que no se pudo crear la conexión
}
?>
```

Una observación final. Nota que al hacer usos de comodines para las marcas posicionales de entrada (arrays de valores con nombre) no hace falta preocuparse de si deben ir o no con comillas ni es necesario hacer sentencias bindparam de modo que el proceso es simple e intuitivo.

Comment: Ahora mismo no esta dando el error que me salía, tu código lo he puesto entre la sql1 y la 2 pero no me inserta el empleado luego.

Comment: ```$sql1 = "INSERT INTO codigos(codigo,descripcion) VALUES ('$codigo_empleado','$descripcion');";
 $sql1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

 $query_codigo = "SELECT codigos.id from codigos where codigos.codigo = ".$_POST["codigo_empleado"].";";
 $result_codigo_id = mysqli_query($conn,$query_codigo);
 
 $linea = mysqli_fetch_row($result_codigo_id);
 
 $codigo_id = isset($linea['id']) ? $linea['id'] : '';

 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO empleados(nombre_completo,codigo) values ('$nombre_completo', '$codigo_id');";
 $sql2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);```

Comment: No se como introducir el codigo bien de formato y completo, perdona pero soy nuevo. sería un detalle que me lo pusieras implementandolo al codigo que falta

Comment: No esta insertando el empleado ahora mismo, pero no se si es por que no consigue el codigo_id o por que esta mal la insert

Comment: Hola. Voy a hacer edición completa del post para corregir todo dentro de 5 horas. Porque ahora tengo que salir. Y quedo sin equipo a mano.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias quevedo, espero tu respuesta cuando usted pueda

Comment: Buenas, lo has podido mirar?

Comment: No pude regresar a tiempo. Hasta ahora me conecto.

Comment: Ya está lista. Te incluí una ilustración usando PDO del uso de sentencias preparadas de modo que no tienes que usar series de ? posicionales y caracteres 'i', 's' etc para ligar los parámetros, que suele ser confuso y hostil.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo que voy a implementar PDO en todo mi proyecto, usando esa conexión y editando lo que tenía hecho. Sobre el código que has editado, me crea el código pero no el empleado y salen 2 warnings que te pongo a continuación

Comment: Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'PDO' has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\beep\cnpdo.php on line 4

Comment: Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\beep\nuevo_empleadopdo.php on line 28

Comment: Vale quevedo, revisando tu código en la línea de guardar el id en el execute estabas ejecutando el valores1 cuando lo que se estaba guardando era valores, he executado $valores y ya me crea el empleado asociado a ese ID

Comment: Editado cuando puedas, sería asi /* GUARDAR EL ID DE CODIGO INTRODUCIDO EN UNA VARIABLE PARA USARLO EN EL INSERT DEL NUEVO EMPLEADO*/
    $query_codigo = "SELECT codigos.id from codigos where codigos.codigo = :codigo;";
    $valores=[':codigo' => $codigo_empleado];
    $prepared_consulta = $connection->prepare($query_codigo);
    $done = $prepared_consulta->execute($valores); // Aquí tenias valores1

Comment: Ya me di cuenta del error que indicas, hay veces en que para ahorrar escritura se copia y pega pedazos del código y arrastré valores1 al lugar en que necesitaba valores. En un momento edito la respuesta y ajusto el detalle.

Answer (score 1):

el error esta en el último `insert` donde le estas pasando la variable `$codigo_id` que tiene asignada un *objeto*.
Algo así quedaría tu `select`:

```
/* GUARDAR EL ID DE CODIGO INTRODUCIDO EN UNA VARIABLE PARA USARLO EN EL INSERT DEL NUEVO EMPLEADO*/
    $sql = "SELECT codigos.id from codigos where codigos.codigo = ".$_POST["codigo_empleado"]." limit 1;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $codigo_id = $row['id'];
```

Comment: Sería posible que me lo pusieras también con el código restante¿

Comment: si implemento tu código me sale esto: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_assoc() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Alfosea\beep\nuevo_empleado.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Alfosea\beep\nuevo_empleado.php on line 16